# EF 6.1.3 Access after migration fails in production environment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have a .NET 4.5.1 WPF application with EF 6.1.3 with SQL Server Express 2014.
After installing on an empty system the database is created by running all migrations and finally seed a few values. This works on hundreds of systems.
Now we have a customer in Litauen, which has a brand new Windows 10 computer, .NET 4.7.

When we install our software, the migrations all run to completion but the seed method is never called. Instead each access to the database triggers the famous "System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'xxx' context has changed since the database was created."

This only happens on this system. Any idea what the reason could be or how it can be debugged?

Thanks for any hints!